Can backtrader plot only with close price?
I can plot with the test data (2005-2006-day-001.txt) when read all columns.
My code is as follows:
import backtrader as bt


class St(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)



data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname='2005-2006-day-001.txt', datetime=0, close=4, open=1, high=2, low=3, volume=5, openinterest=6, dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d'))

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addstrategy(St)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot() # this works

But if only read close price from the test data, cerebro.plot() raise ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf
import backtrader as bt


class St(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)



data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname='2005-2006-day-001.txt', datetime=0, close=4, open=-1, high=-1, low=-1, volume=-1, openinterest=-1, dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d'))

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addstrategy(St)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot() # this raise ValueError

Common fund which I want to backtest only has close price.
Can backtrader plot only with close price? Or any other advices?

I found settings some kwargs to enable the plot.
cerebro.plot(open=False, high=False, low=False, volume=False)

But it is better to use etf instead of common fund. Etf has all prices. Backtrader usually use open price to order. You don't want to miss this data.
